# Improving performance of condtitional query inside LINQ enumerator

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got some code that looks like this, using .NET 3.5 (customer requirement):

```
void Process (ActionState state)
{
    var orderItemQuery = from OrderItem item in order.OrderItems
                           orderby item.OrderLineNumber ascending
                           select item;

    foreach (OrderItem item in orderItemQuery)
    {
        ActionData actionData;
        switch (state)
        {
            case ActionState.Prepare:
                actionData = (
                    from ActionData ad in db.ActionDataTable
                      where ad.ObjectId == item.ProductId
                      select ad
                ).First();

            case ActionState.QualityCheck:
                actionData = (
                    from ActionData ad in db.ActionDataTable
                      where ad.ObjectId == item.OrderItemId
                      select ad
                ).First();

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Essentially the results of the first query are iterated through, and a particular foreign key is used to fetch an `ActionData` record from the database, based upon the current `ActionState`. In reality there's a bit more nesting and a few checks here and there, but it's essentially the same.

This initially worked great for test databases, but a customer just sent me a copy of their live data and it's hideously slow. It takes around 15 minutes to run the entire batch, including some other processing. After running the code through a performance tester, I discovered that the slowest part of the entire process was the `.First()` call on each of the cases.

If this were plain SQL, I'd compile a stored procedure outside of the loop based on the value of `state`, and use that. Since I can't do that, what's the alternative? How can I speed this up?

Comment: Note that it is not really the .First() that is the the performance issue, it is that the Linq statement does not execute until the .First() executes.  So the actual peformance hit is probably within the Linq statement itself.

Comment: Linq statement is executed on foreach. So it spam sql server with 100500 requests (one request per order).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your code execute 100500 requests to db. You need to get what you want in one request. To do this you need to write right linq query. something like this:

```
if(state!=ActionState.Prepare&&state!=ActionState.QualityCheck)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
var orderSelector = state == ActionState.Prepare
                             ?o=>o.ProductId
                             :?o=>o.OrderItemId
var orderWithActionQuery  = order.OrderItems.Orderby(o => o.OrderLineNumber).GroupJoin(
        db.ActionDataTable,
        orderSelector,
        ad => ad.ObjectId,
        (x, y) => new { item = x, actionDatas = y })
        .Select(c => new {item = c.item, actionData = c.actionDatas.FirstOrDefault()});    
foreach(var orderWithActionData in orderWithActionQuery)
{
     //orderWithActionData.item is orderItem
     //orderWithActionData.actionData is ation data of this item
}
```

In this code request to database will be send in line with foreach. it will be single request and performance will be good

Comment: This looks good. Only thing I don't quite get is why the loop runs on `actionData`, since there's only one `ActionData` entry per `OrderItem`. Could you clarify how this works?

Comment: actionDataQuery contains ActionData's for all orders. It is equevalent to inner join in sql

Comment: But then I'd still need to query for the order records within the loop... isn't this just turning the problem inside-out?

Comment: `actionDataQuery` retrieves all the actions data, one for each order item. I think this one is in the good direction but then it's missing the `First()` part, if you want just the first and you might have more than one action data per order item then that piece is missing.

Comment: no. you don't need to do it. It will be single request that get all ActionDatas for all orders at once.

Comment: As far as the table is concerned, each order item may or may not have an action data item. However, this method is only given the orders that are actionable, which as such will *always* have one action data item per order item. Essentially I'd like to join them onto the table, but couldn't figure out how to "hybridise" the return type to allow for all columns to be returned.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov That's not useful - I need to be able to iterate through *per order* and *per order item*, because I update certain state data and structures at the end of each.

Comment: So you need to do left outer join of this tables, don't you? It could be done to. I shall update my answer.

Comment: The you just need to project: `select new { Item = item, Data = ad }`, supposing you are doing the join of both tables. If this is your problem I can try to write an answer.

Comment: Cheers, I'll try it out tomorrow (home time, yay!)

Comment: The `orderSelector` part gives me `type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'` - not sure how to cast this properly.

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting this error: "The type arguments for method `SelectMany<TSource,TCollection,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>,Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>>, Func<TSource,TCollection,TResult>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: Managed to get this _almost_ working. Turns out the `x => x.actionDatas.FirstOrDefault()` part is wrong, since it's expecting an `IEnumerable`. Wrapping it in `new [] { ... }` does the job. Seems to have problems with any situation where `order.OrderItems` contains more than one entry, though.

Comment: Try to change SelectMany on Select(c => new {item = c.item, actionData = c.actionDatas.FirstOrDefault()});

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the database for each item in the loop.
You should bake the queries together in one query.
This way the query should be executed as one large query on the database and the result should be fetched in on go from the SQL server.

You could easily spot the problem by using SQL Profiler and see the vast number of `select x,y,z,... from ActionData` queries.

This one selects both the OrderItem and ActionData to a temporary anonymous type that contains both values.

```
void Process (ActionState state)
{
    var orderItemQuery = from OrderItem item in order.OrderItems
                           orderby item.OrderLineNumber ascending
                           select item;
    var orderItemWithActionDataQuery = 
                from item in orderItemQuery
                select new{Item = item,
                           ActionData = (
                    from ActionData ad in db.ActionDataTable
                      where ad.ObjectId == item.ProductId
                      select ad
                ).First()};

        switch (state)
        {
            case ActionState.Prepare:
                // done
                break;

            case ActionState.QualityCheck:
                orderItemWithActionDataQuery = 
                from item in orderItemQuery
                select new{Item = item,
                           ActionData = (
                    from ActionData ad in db.ActionDataTable
                      where ad.ObjectId == item.OrderItemId
                      select ad
                ).First()};

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }



    foreach (var combinedItem in orderItemWithActionDataQuery)
    {
        OrderItem item = combinedItem.Item;
        ActionData actionData = combinedItem.ActionData;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work. This code doesn't compile. Where's the loop that provides `item`? Even if you include the loop, we're back to the original problem of having the query switched inside of a loop.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the loop variable, fixed that now.
The query is switched outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to profile your query. I suspect you are hitting an n+1 issue because your database is hit each time .First is called. Since you are doing this in a loop, your database may see excessive hits. Evaluate state outside of the loop and set separate queries based on state without the looping.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, but I don't know *how* to generate the query outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this to be quite efficient:

Instead of putting your Select into a For loop, generate an array of OrderItemIds and use Array.Contains();

```
void Process (ActionState state)
{
    var orderItemQuery = from OrderItem item in order.OrderItems
                           orderby item.OrderLineNumber ascending
                           select item;

    IEnumerable<ActionData> actionDatas = null;

    if (state ==  ActionState.Prepare)
    {
        var productIds = orderItemQuery.Select(o => o.ProductId).ToArray();
        actionDatas = db.ActionDataTable.Where(a => productIds.Contains(a.ObjectId));
    }
    else if(state == ActionState.QualityCheck)
    {
        var orderItemIds = orderItemQuery.Select(o => o.OrderItemId).ToArray();
        actionDatas = db.ActionDataTable.Where(a => orderItemIds.Contains(a.ObjectId));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

        // Do stuff against the complete list of actionDatas without requerying.
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could work, but it relies on having all of the results in memory. For some customers, there may be a few million rows.

Comment: Without more information, I'm not sure how to help. Perhaps a db View would be more useful. Leveraging joins could help scope the result set down. If you have additional conditions you scope your query down by iterating through each condition. If you had an upper and lower bound, you could use Skip() and Take() to limit the number of results in each query. HTH